# Google API error when trying to export the map reference

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a page in which I want to include the google maps API, I already have the script connected to my page, but I have a problem. I need to be able to export the result of the `initMap` (function which asks to initialize the Google Maps API in the script) and I can't do it because it gives me errors, I have 2 js files:

inicializar.js:

```js
export function initMap() {
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: { lat: 40.23238925881008, lng: -100.70052936550995 }
    });
}
```

codigo.js:

```js
import { initMap } from "./inicializar.js"
const mapita = initMap();

console.log(mapita);
```

and the html where these scripts are plus the API one:

```html
<script src="/build/js/codigo.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="/build/js/inicializar.js"></script>

<script async
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

The map is displayed but this appears in the console, should I give it importance? Or how could I solve this error in the console?:

```
inicializar.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at initMap (inicializar.js:1:27)
    at codigo.js:1:52

localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) me {message: 'initMap is not a function', stack: 'Error\n    at new me (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…ibraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap:313:231', name: 'InvalidValueError'}

js?key=${key}&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap:486     GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick that you need perhaps to get the map working from within a module requires a slight change to the loading of the google api script.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Importing Maps initMap()</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:2rem auto;
                border:2px solid black;
                border-radius:1rem;
                box-shadow:0 0 2rem rgba(0,0,0,0.5  );
            }
        </style>
        <script src='./gmap.js' type='module'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The maps API script is not loaded statically in the HTML page - it is added dynamically from within the `module`

The exporting of the map is virtually the same as the original but I added the apikey as an exportable property also. This apikey is accessed in the module.

```
/*
    exportmap.js - map definition ( inicializar.js )
    
    This is where we generate the map functionality 
    and export it.
*/

const apikey='AIzaSy.....................tA';

function initMap() {
    let latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(40.23238925881008,-100.70052936550995);
    let map=new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng
    });
    map.setCenter( latlng );
    return map;
}
export { initMap, apikey }
```

Then the module that is loaded in the HTML - this `imports` the map definition and apikey and declares these as global properties of the window object before adding a dynamically build api script.

```
/*
    module - gmap.js ( codigo.js )
    
    This imports the initMap function and initialises the whole map
    - it dynamically adds the maps api script rather than this being
    hardcoded in the page.
*/

import * as obj from './exportmap.js';
/*
    create the exported items as global properties
    of the window object. This is the trick!!
*/
window.initMap=obj.initMap;
window.apikey=obj.apikey;



/*
    Generate the script uri and then dynamically load the map
*/
let uri=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${apikey}&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap`;
let script=document.createElement('script');
    script.src=uri;
    script.async=true;
    script.defer=true;


    
document.body.appendChild( script );
```